# How can I add new Java components to NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, components

I downloaded some new Java component, and now I want to add them to netbeans, but I don't know how.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of component is it? Do you mean a [JAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_file) file?

If so, then

- open the project you are working on.
- Select the project.
- Right click on it and select "Properties"
- Select "Libraries"
- Select "Add external jar"
- Browse to the JAR file and add it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about adding a GUI component to the NetBeans palette, then check out the NetBeans help file on using the palette manager.  If this doesn't help, you'll want to clarify your question greatly as it's somewhat ambiguous.